# Running Rscript from cmd

Tags: r, rweka

My R Script is

```
library(randomForest)
library(RWeka)
p= read.arff("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\Weka_data\\training_data_short_term.arff")
t= read.arff("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\Weka_data\\test_short_term.arff")
random <- randomForest(DEC~.,p)
random
sink("F:\\Project_files\\temp\\trial.txt")
print(random)
sink()
```

which is running fine on R. but  i am getting error while calling this from Cmd using command

```
Rscript F:\Project_files\R_script\Random.R
```

error is :

> Error in .jnew("weka/core/Instances", .jcast(reader,
>   "java/io/Reader")) :   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   weka/core/Instances : Unsupported majo r.minor version 51.0 Calls:
>   read.arff -> .jnew -> .External Execution halted

Comment: Looks like they are getting different versions of Java. Sure they are running with the same version of R? Does `R.home()` show the same path from R and Rscript?

Comment: yes ,the output for both of them is  `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1"`

Comment: okay, the problem was with R version,my RWeka library was for 3.3.2 and I was using 3.3.1 .Thanks a lot for showing me path.